# Word for to organize, to make clearer the structure of

Tags: single-word-requests, synonyms, american-english

Like building a diagram, or modelling something. Putting lines together on a graph that represent something. Organizing. Working to make the structure of something more clear / evident.

Ideally, I'm looking for a somewhat flourished, attractive word.

Comment: Can you provide a sample sentence with the word you want left blank?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about “elucidate”? [TFD](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/elucidate)

> v. tr.   To make clear or plain, especially by explanation; clarify.
>
> v.intr.   To explain or clarify something.

You could easily say

> John looked confused by Karen’s business plan, so Karen quickly elucidated with a graph.
>
> Watson struggled to put the clues together until Holmes elucidated.